# TFS says I am not a member of the Team Foundation Valid Users group, but I am

Tags: authentication, visual-studio-2013, tfs, credentials

I'm trying to check in changes to TFS using VS2013.  When I hit the button to submit, TFS returns the following error, "TF14002: The identity {domain} \ {oldaccount} is not a member of the Team Foundation Valid Users group."

Background:  my account name has been changed to {newaccount} from {oldaccount}.

When I first started working at this company I'm almost certain I set up my TFS with my old account.  But I thought I deleted all that stuff related to my old account and reset everything to my new account.  My lead tech has even shown me the account mngmnt screen with my new account name.  And I've been able to check out items with my new account name.

I performed the following steps to try to "clean out" TFS:

•  I copied all of my changed files to a back-up location.

•  I undid all changes in TFS (note that TFS has been allowing me to check out files to edit).

•  I deleted the TFS entry in Credential Manager per a suggestion online.

•  I deleted my Workspace.

•  I even deleted my TFS server.

•  I Rebooted my computer.

•  I reconnected to the TFS server.

•  I rebuilt my Workspace.

•  I restored my changed files from my back-up location.

At this point I tried checking-in my changes again but got the same error message as above.

Any suggestions?

Note that I do NOT have access to the TFS server, much less permissions to perform any sort of admin on it (and I don't know the person who would).  So any suggestions beyond simply tweaking my computer will require a trip through the bureaucratic swamp.

One possible positive (related to this issue) is that we've been informed that a number of us need to downgrade from "Ultimate" to "Professional" so if your suggestion is to reinstall Visual Studio, the upside is that I'll be doing that soon anyway.

Thanks,
Doug

EDIT:
Additional Info: I deleted everything in this folder:

C:\Users\ ...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

... but I'm still seeing the error.

UPDATE 1/24/2015:
I did finally "downgrade" from Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate to VS2013 Professional, but I'm still experiencing the same error.  Might there be a table in the TFS database that still has an entry for my old account that could be joining to my computer name &/or new account name when TFS goes to look up my account info when I check in my changes?  I am getting desperate for an answer!

An addendum:  when the sys-admins changed my account name they did not update my computer itself, so I'm still using C:\Users\{oldaccount}.  I can't believe that would make a difference but you never know....

**UPDATE 2/27/2016:**
Sorry for not updating this sooner.  I resolved this issue with the help of our DBAs:

There is a table named **Constants** which contains the domain part and a field named “NamePart”.  The resolution was to simply update “NamePart” to “{newaccount}” from “{oldaccount}”.  This table also has an SID field which is the user’s SID from the computer’s Registry.  You'd only change the SID if a new login to your computer was created.  In my case, there was no new login account, just a change to my login account -name-, therefore, no new SID.

And a side note, for situations when one’s email is also spelled incorrectly, there is also the **ADObjects** table which contains a field named “MailNickName”.  This field should be updated as well when a user name is misspelled.  For instance, I had the DBA update that field to change “Dug@NotReal.net” to “Doug@NotReal.net”.

Updating the **Constants** table is imperative to making TFS work; updating **ADObjects** is only relevant if an alias isn’t included to forward mail from the one email address to the other.

Comment: From your start menu type 'credential manager' and look at your windows credentials stored in the vault...it may well be your old account - if so just delete them and reopen visual studio

Comment: @sburgess123, if you read my entire question, that is #3 in the list of things I tried.  But I went ahead and deleted other credentials that did not appear to be associated with TFS and that were not specifically associated with any other applications (such as Outlook),  Deleting those other credentials made no difference either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have posted my answer (update 2/27/2016) as an official Answer. I resolved this issue with the help of our DBAs:

There is a table named **Constants** which contains the domain part and a field named “*NamePart*”. The resolution was to simply update “*NamePart*” to “{newaccount}” from “{oldaccount}”. This table also has an *SID* field which is the user’s SID from the computer’s Registry. You'd only change the *SID* if a new login to your computer was created. In my case, there was no new login account, just a change to my login account -name-, therefore, no new SID.

And a side note, for situations when one’s email is also spelled incorrectly, there is also the **ADObjects** table which contains a field named “*MailNickName*”. This field should be updated as well when a user name is misspelled. For instance, I had the DBA update that field to change “Dug@NotReal.net” to “Doug@NotReal.net”.

Updating the **Constants** table is imperative to making TFS work; updating **ADObjects** is only relevant if an alias isn’t included to forward mail from the one email address to the other.

Comment: We had the same issue, but managed to fix it by simply disconnecting Visual Studio from TFS and then reconnecting.

Answer (score 2):

I found a file called `VersionControl.config` inside of the 
`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache\Volatile\` folder that had my old domain username in. Changed it to my new one and it started working again.

I was having the problem with shell integration, Visual Studio actually worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, @Zymotik.  While your suggestion might work for some, it would not have worked for me.  As I mentioned in my last update from 2/27/2016, my old account name was still in the Constants table (in the TFS database) in the NamePart field.

I had first tried working with the DBAs at the company but they brushed me off.  My manager allowed me to contact Microsoft support and they helped a little.  I eventually went back to the DBAs and almost demanded they help me (allow me to) view the relevant tables.  That's how I discovered the resolution on my own.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution did not work for a developer in our company. On of my colleagues came with the simple idea to do a "undo checkout", which worked. After that the check-in en checkout worked well again.